# How to make this sql code in "LINQ"?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

```
select top 10 JobId,Title,

(SELECT TOP 1 Authorized FROM Company WHERE CompanyId=Job.CompanyId) as CompanyName

from Job
```

How to make this sql code in "LINQ" ?

Comment: Use LinqPad ... that's the answer. It can generate the Linq expression for you. Else see MSDN documentation

Comment: @Rahul Linqpad can show you the SQL generated by a Linq query, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
var query = (from j in job 
   select new 
   {
      j.JobId, 
      j.Title,
      CompanyName = (from c in from Company 
                        where  c.CompanyId=j.CompanyId) 
                        select c.Authorized ).First()
   }
 ).Take(10);
```

This is assuming you will always have at least one company otherwise you may have to use `FirstOrDefault()` .